# Firebase increase sign-up quota

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are using Firebase on our project and we are expecting a lot of traffic on the website in the upcoming days.

We saw the firebase sign-up limit, and we are wondering if you found a way to disable it?
Or increase it above 1 000, we exceptionally need 50 000 for 8 days.

[Image of firebase auth quota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aebi5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

You can request a temporary increase of sign-up quota in the [authentication control panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers) in the Firebase console. There is no way to disable quota altogether.

If you need something that is not covered by the quota settings in this page, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help.

Comment: Thanks you, done, we're waiting for their answer then. I hope it can be changed on their side because we're waiting more than 20 k signup in the upcoming days.

Comment: If these are real users, you should need to do anything. The quota that you can change is per IP, so typically you'd only hit that quota in testing, or when creating your accounts in the backend, in which case I recommend using the `auth:import` CLI command or the Admin SDK's `importUsers` API, neither of which is subject to these quotas.